# PHP displaying updated values

Tags: php, shopping-cart, display

the quantity is an array of items

```
<td>
<input type="text" size="4" name="qty[<?php echo $pro_id;?>]"style="text-
align:center" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty']; ?>">

</td>
<?php
```

the update function works perfectly

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$ip=getIp();
$sql = "UPDATE cart SET qty=? where p_id=? and ip_add=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql); 
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $pro_id=>$qty) {
$stmt->bind_param("iis", $qty, $pro_id, $ip);
    $stmt->execute();
}
}
```

this is what i used to display the new quantity, but the values are displayed in the incorrect product field

```
$sql = $con->query("select * from cart where p_id='$pro_id'");
$row=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$_SESSION['qty']=$row['qty'];
?>
```

the button which updates the cart

```
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update quantity"></td>
<td><button style="height:20px;width:128px">
<a href="index.php"style="color:black">Continue Shopping</a></button></td>
<td><button><a href="checkout.php" style="color:black">Checkout</a></button>   
</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the quantity is a array and the data in the database is correct you need the SESSION qty as a Array!

Try this:

```
$sql = $con->query("select * from cart where p_id='$pro_id'");
$row=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$_SESSION[$pro_id]['qty']=$row['qty'];
```

and this

```
<td>
<input type="text" size="4" name="qty[<?php echo $pro_id;?>]"style="text-    
align:center" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[$pro_id]['qty']; ?>">

</td>
<?php
```

Comment: thanks for the reply dude, i tried this but it did not work, it outputs this error in all fields     :                                                                                            <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 3 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\ecommerce\ca